# How can I encapsulate a $http.put into a function that does something and then returns a pass or fail promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
var requests = $scope.grid.data
           .filter(function (rowData, i) {
              return !angular.equals(rowData, $scope.grid.backup[i]);
           })
           .map(function (rowData, i) {
              var entityId = rowData[entityIdColumn];
              return $http.put('/api/' + $scope.entityType + '/' + entityId, rowData);
           });
```

How can I replace:

```
$http.put('/api/' + $scope.entityType + '/' + entityId, rowData);
```

with a function that does the put, acts on a pass or fail result and then returns a pass or fail promise ?

Also I was using $q.all(requests) to run all the functions created. Is there another way that I could run these without using $q ?

Answer (score 0):

`$http.put` already returns a promise. Just chain (`then(success_callback, error_callback)`) against the result to perform actions on success or failure and return the result of chain.

Here's an attempt at a chained `$http.put` response with some comments about possible functionality:

```
function putEntityData(rowData) {
    var promise;

    promise = $http.put('/api/' + $scope.entityType + '/' + entityId, rowData)
    .then(function(response) {
        // Process success here
        if (response.something == 'relevant') {
            return response.somethingElse;
        }
    }, function(reason) {
        // Process error here, you can correct and return a value if salvage-able
        if (reason == 'correctable') {
            return "Corrected Response";
        } else {
            // Otherwise, continue to reject the response with $q.reject()
            return $q.reject(reason);
        }
    });

    return promise;
}

var requests = $scope.grid.data
.filter(function (rowData, i) {
    return !angular.equals(rowData, $scope.grid.backup[i]);
})
.map(function (rowData, i) {
    var entityId = rowData[entityIdColumn];
    return putEntityData(rowData);
});
```

Comment: But how can I do something based on the success or failure and then return a success or failure also ?

Comment: That's how promises work. You attach callbacks for success and failures. I'll amend my answer with examples later today since I'm on my phone.